# Efficient means of mass converting thousands of different find and replaces within one file

Tags: replace

I am trying to convert a map file for some SNP data I want to use from Affy ids to dbSNP rs ids.

I am trying to find an effective way to this. I have the annotation file for the Axiom array from which the data comes from, so I know the proper ids.

I was wondering if anyone could suggest a good bash/Python/Perl based method to do this. It amounts to >100,000 different replacements. The idea I had in mind was the

sed -i 's/*Affy#*/*rs#*/g' *filename*

method, but I figure this would not be the most efficient. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: It takes well under 2 seconds to replace "Affx" with "rs" in that file in Vim, just for a rough example. If you're only doing this once, forget efficiency and do anything that works, it's going to take at most a handful of minutes. What exactly is the conversion - where do you have the replacement numbers stored? The file is tab separated which is easy to read in Python with the csv module, so I'm thinking read the file in, lookup/replace in memory, then write the file out, but it depends how you have the replacement data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python code, assuming your substitutions are stored in subs.csv:

```
import csv

subs = dict(csv.reader(open('subs.csv'), delimiter='\t'))
source = csv.reader(open('all_snp.map'), delimiter='\t')
dest = csv.writer(open('all_snp_out.map', 'wb'), delimiter='\t')

for row in source:
    row[1] = subs.get(row[1], row[1])
    dest.writerow(row)
```

The line `row[1] = subs.get(row[1], row[1])`:  row[1] is the Affx column, and it replaces it with a dictionary lookup which either gets the rsNumber equivalent if there is one, or returns the original Affx bit if there isn't one.